# Perforce tasks for MS Build

Tags: msbuild, perforce

Are there any community MSBuild tasks for Perforce (e.g. even just basic syncing)?

Neither the MSBuild Community tasks or MSBuildExtenstion pack seem to have any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the open source [MSBuild Contrib](http://msbuildcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MSBuild%20Equivalent%20Tasks) project has some p4 tasks. I've never used them before so I can't say how well they work. If they don't work you can always write your own tasks, they are pretty easy if you are able to write .NET code. If you don't want to go that route you can use the [Exec task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) to execute command line commands to perform those operations for you.

Comment: Those tasks actually use nAnt - they aren't native MSBuild tasks

Comment: In the end I went the Exec task route.  I'll see if there is any desire to update the contrib project.

Comment: The link no longer works, and its redirection doesn't either.  This might be the latest: https://github.com/scottdorman/MSBuildContrib